# C++ Inheritance of functions, passing in arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

Base class : `Employee`
Derived class : `Regular`

**Employee.cpp**

```
void Employee::setValue(string id, string name, double s, int n)
{
    empID = id;
    empName = name;
    salary = s;
}
```

**Regular.cpp**

```
void Regular::setValue(string id, string name, double s, int n) 
{
    annualLeave = n;
}
```

`Employee::setValue()` only stores the first 3 arguments passed in, but not `int n`, too.

I'm supposed to inherit that `setValue()` in `Regular::setValue()` and then just pass in the arguments, but this time store `int n` to `annualLeave`.

How do I do that?

Or, is there a way for me to set `int n` in the base class for the child class?

Comment: It doesn't look like the right place to use inheritance.

Comment: call `Employee::setValue(id, name, salary);`. And why does Employee take `int n` when it doesn't use it?

Comment: Why don't you add `Employee::setValue(id, name, s, n);` to Regular::setValue() ?

Comment: The easy way is for the derived method to invoke the base method.  You did not mention which class is base,  so, for example, with Regular the derived class, Regular::setValue() sets annualLeave, then invokes the Employee::setValue(), where the other 3 values are stored.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the base class's implementation:

```
void Regular::setValue(string id, string name, double s, int n) {
    annualLeave = n;
    return Employee::setValue(std::move(id), std::move(name), s);
}
```

Otherwise, make base class polymorphic:

```
struct Employee {
    void setValue(string id, string name, double s, int n) {
        empID = std::move(id);
        empName = std::move(name);
        salary = s;
        setLeave(n);
    }
    virtual ~Employee() {}
protected:
    virtual void setLeave(int) = 0;
    string empID;
    string empName;
    double salary;
};

struct Regular: Employee {
private:
    void setLeave(int n) override { annualLeave = n; }
    int annualLeave;
};
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau Excusez-moi?

Comment: You had issues in your code (you had a `void` method trying to return a value. And a pure virtual method that not all descendants may want to override, and a variable that didn't match the OP's code). So I fixed them for you, that's all.  you are welcome.

Comment: Hmm? I. If you haven't noticed, my void method did not try to "return a value" it merely passed control to an (equally) void method. _Returning_ a base class's implementation's result is a good illustration of how this redirection usually works, regardless void or not. II. Pure virtual method is again a demonstration of concept, if OP wanted it to have a default implementation, it wouldn't make trouble to add one. Moreover you've added an issue: it's polymorphic _storing_, not _storage_. So, once again, besides renaming a member variable—what was the purpose of your so vast edit?

Answer (score 0):

**If necessary to keep a single-signature setValue function**, it is possible to do it like that:

-

Includes:

```
#include <any>
#include <map>
#include <string>
```

-

Employee.h:

```
class CEmployee
{
protected:
    virtual void setValue(std::map<std::string, std::any> &info);

    int m_empID = 0;
    std::string m_empName = {'\0'};
    int m_salary = 0;
}
```

Employee.cpp:

```
void CEmployee::setValue(std::map<std::string, std::any> &info)
{
    std::any item;

    item = info["empID"];
    if (item.has_value())
        m_empID = std::any_cast<int>(item); // int

    item = info["empName"];
    if (item.has_value())
        m_empName = std::any_cast<std::string>(item); // std::string 

    item = info["salary"];
    if (item.has_value())
        m_salary = std::any_cast<int>(item); // int 
}
```

-

Regular.h:

```
class CRegular : public CEmployee
{
public:
    void setValue(std::map<std::string, std::any> &info) override;

protected:
    std::string m_annualLeave = {'\0'};
}
```

Regular.cpp:

```
void CRegular::setValue(std::map<std::string, std::any> &info)
{
    std::any item;

    CEmployee::setValue(info);

    item = info["annualLeave"];
    if (item.has_value())
        m_annualLeave = std::any_cast<std::string>(item); // std::string 
}
```

-

& call it like that:

```
void MyClass::HardcodedExample()
{
    CRegular regular_employee;
    std::map<std::string, std::any> info, update;

    info["empID"] = { 100 };
    info["empName"] = { std::string("Trump") };
    info["salary"] = { 1000000 };
    info["annualLeave"] = { std::string("29 Jul 2018") };
    regular_employee.setValue(info); // Set all info

    // Or:
    update["annualLeave"] = { std::string("29 Dec 2018") };
    regular_employee.setValue(update); // Update just "annualLeave"

    // Or:
    update["salary"] = { 1200000 };
    update["annualLeave"] = { std::string("04 Jul 2018") };
    regular_employee.setValue(update); // Update "salary" & "annualLeave"
}
```

-

Otherwise, setValue with 3 parameters to base-class, & with 4 parameters to the derived-class (that calls to the base-class with the 3 parameters and sets by itself the 4th one) - similar to what @RemyLebeauis offers - is a better solution.

-

& better to use #define / enum keys instead of string-keys (& change the key-type of the map accordingly), but this is a different issue.